# Symfony2 TidyUp the code

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

is there any possibility, to make the code more smart? I'm a beginner in working with Symfony, that's why my code looks like this:

If there are ideas, how to shorten the code, or make more efficent, the ideas are welcome!

```
/**
@Route(
 *     path = "/taskmanager/user/{user_id}",
 *     name = "taskmanager"
 * )
 * @Template()
 */
public function taskManagerAction($user_id, Request $request)
{

    /* #### NEW TASK FORM #### */

    $task = new Task();
    $log = new Log();

    $addTaskForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
    $addTaskForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($addTaskForm->isValid()):

        /* User Object of current Users task list */
        $userid = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
            ->find($user_id);

        /* User ID of current logged in User */
        $editor = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $editor_id = $editor->getId();

        /* Editor Object of current logged in User */
        $editorid = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
            ->find($editor_id);

        $task->setDone(FALSE);
        $task->setUser($userid);
        $task->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
        $task->setDateDone(NULL);


        $log->setUser($userid);
        $log->setEditor($editorid);
        $log->setLogTitle('Neue Aufgabe hinzugefügt');
        $log->setDate(new \DateTime());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->persist($log);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('taskmanager', array('user_id' => $user_id)));

    endif;

    /* #### TASK LISTS #### */

    $priorities = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'Hoch', 'class' => 'high' ),
        1 => array('name' => 'Normal', 'class' => 'normal' ),
        2 => array('name' => 'Niedrig', 'class' => 'low' )
    );

    $tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $user_id));

    $count_task_done = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $user_id, 'done' => TRUE));

    $count_task_open = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $user_id, 'done' => FALSE));

    /* #### USER LISTS #### */

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
        ->findBy(array('isActive' => 1, 'isAdmin' => 0));

    return array(
        'addTaskForm' => $addTaskForm->createView(),
        'message' => '',
        'list_user' => $user,
        'tasks' => $tasks,
        'current_user' => $user_id,
        'count_task_done' => $count_task_done,
        'count_task_open' => $count_task_open,
        'priorities' => $priorities,
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner, I advise you to learn Symfony from its cookbook which is very instructive.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html

1. Create a form handler to manage your form.
2. You can also use the Factory pattern to instanciate your objects.
3. Don't hesitate to create services.

All of these advices are in the cookbook.

Hope it was helpful.
Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you for the tips with the form handler and services. Up to now I didn't tried services. Thank you :)